Sync nonMatter device information to Google
When I developed the Bridge Matter application for use with nonMatter devices such as Zigbee, BLE. Because these devices already exist in our ecosystem and have information about floors, rooms, rules, scenes, and schedules. But when posted to Google, this information seems to be out of sync. Therefore, it is easy for information synchronization to occur between the two ecosystems. And provides a bad user experience.
Is there a way to synchronize this information through Bridge Matter?
I tried adding the device's floor, room, and action information when performing AddDeviceEndpoint, but this information doesn't seem to be synchronized, so when the device connects to the network, Google forces me to configure this information from scratch.


At this time, there is not a direct path from the matter data model to handle such assignments in GHA.
If the bridge is also capable of implementing a cloud integration with Google, deduplication of both the matter and end device can be performed and the matter device can be automatically structured.

More information in this regard can be found here.
